# Numpy signal processing: Efficiently summarize subarrays of consecutive nonzero elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, signal-processing

so, I'm working with FFT data that when thoroughly cleaned should look like many many zeros and an occasional large number. What I have at the moment is many zeros and an occasional short subarray of largish numbers. as an example,

`ydata=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,9,3, 1, 0, 2, 9, 0])`
`xdata=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])`

I'm using an array of consecutive integers for xdata, but these values could be any sequence of strictly increasing numbers.

What I would like to do is set all current y values to 0 and add values corresponding to the non-zero subarrays. for each subarray, the y value should be the sum of the elements in the sub array and it should the index closest to the weighted sum of the indices of the subarray.

as an example, the first subarray of consecutive nonzero elements in ydata is [1,2,3] with corresponding x values [4,5,6]. the sum of the y values is 6, the weighted sum of the x values is (4+10+18)/6 which rounds to 5. Following this pattern I'd like to get.

`ydata=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,13,0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0])`
`xdata=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10,11,12,13,14,15])`

if instead we have
`ydata=np.array([1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,0,9,3, 1, 0, 2, 9, 0])`
`xdata=np.array([.1,.4,.6,3,4.1,4.2,4.3,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])`

then ydata should be
`ydata=np.array([6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,13,0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0])`

I could do this using non-numpy iteration, but that would be impractical with data the size I'm working with. would anyone know of some good way to do this through numpythonic means?

Comment: It's confusing what you're asking. Your examples are 1-dimensional arrays but your question mentions subarrays, presumably 2-dimensional arrays? Perhaps you could give some better examples that match what you're referring to in your question.

Comment: well, what is the relation between np.array([0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,9,3, 1, 0, 2, 9, 0]) and np([1,2,3])? if it is not a subarray, a subsequence then? @russhoppa

Comment: There might be a bigger speedup if you're open to precompiling a regular loop using numba instead of using numpy

Comment: @pho, I don't think that will be practical for me

Comment: @Alosapien, Is `xdata` just a consecutive sequence of numbers reflecting indices?

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe that's accurate terminology but I wasn't catching it. So You just want to sum these non-zero subarrays and put the result at the index of the first non-zero place in the `xdata` for every non-zero subarray?

Comment: @russhoppa you are correct up to the indexing. for example, the sum of [2,9] is 11,. the corresponding xvalues (and in the example indices) are [13,14], with a weighted average of (13*2+14*9)/11=13.818181... which rounds to 14

Comment: no all that can be guaranteed about the xdata is that they are strictly increasing. I'll update the question though. @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate a few things here:

First, get the cumulative sum of the entire array:

```
cs = np.cumsum(ydata)
```

Next, find locations where the current element is nonzero, the next element is zero, and the cumulative sum is not zero:

```
filter_locs = (ydata != 0) & (cs != 0)
filter_locs[:-1] = filter_locs[:-1] & (ydata[1:] == 0)
```

The new values can be derived from the cumulative sum at these locations:

```
new_values = cs[filter_locs]
new_values[1:] -= new_values[:-1]
```

We can do a similar operation on the `xdata * ydata` to get the indices:

```
cs_x = np.cumsum(xdata * ydata)
weighted_totals = cs_x[filter_locs]
weighted_totals[1:] -= weighted_totals[:-1]

new_indices = np.round(weighted_totals / new_values).astype(int)
```

And finally, set the indices in an array of zeros:

```
new_data = np.zeros_like(ydata)
new_data[new_indices] = new_values
```

Which gives us the desired array:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,  0])
```

---

If `xdata` is not an array of indices, then the maximum possible index in the output array is the maximum value of `xdata`, so instead of `new_data = np.zeros_like(ydata)`, do:

```
max_possible_index = int(np.round(xdata.max()))
new_data = np.zeros((max_possible_index+1,))
```

Comment: This works wonderfully when xdata is the indices of ydata, but what if xdata is just an irregular increasing sequence (of same length)? this already works for the thing that I wanted to do, xdata for me happens to be a sequence of increasing evenly spaced floats, but I just tested this on an irregular increasing sequence and it did not work.

Comment: @Alosapien when `xdata` is not an array of indices of `ydata`, the calculated `new_indices` can exceed the size of `ydata`, so `new_data = np.zeros_like(ydata)` is inadequate. I added a line to my answer to initialize the new array using the maximum possible index.

Comment: my mistake. the program did run with both arrays the same size. I'm not sure why it did not work the first time but your answer was valid for irregularly increasing xdata as well. it also works with complex ydata, but I'm not entirely sure why

Comment: ah, for complex data redefine cs_x=np.cumsum(xdata*np.absolute(ydata)) since the weights need to be the norm, not the actaul complex values

Comment: a bit more complicated, posting for posterity: also create new_values_abs=cs_abs[filter_locs], have new_values_abs[1:]-=new_values_abs[:-1] and redefine new_indices= np.round(weighted_totals / new_values_abs).astype(int).